# Various HTML/CSS issues

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site, and it's pretty much done.
I'm trying to have the hills at the bottom of the page, which is currently working. I'm trying to get the footer at the bottom of the hills, but it goes at the bottom of the viewport. I'm using the usual `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`.
Theses are the main issues. I'd also like for the text to not go over the hills, since it makes it hard to read. The only way I can do this is making the footer bigger, or a filler between the footer and the main test area.
I can get all these working, but only on their own, not all together.
I wont post any specific code, since there's a lot of it, so if you can help visit [www.helpusplan.co.uk](http://www.helpusplan.co.uk).
Thanks for any help

Comment: *I wont post any pseicifc code, since there's a lot of it*. Please post specific questions and include relevant code/markup/stylesheets. **I don't know what I'm doing, please fix my problems** is not a legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain your problem is that you have your hills image attached to the `body` of your document.  Attach it instead to the `footer` (I mean, come on, you already named the image `footer.png`) and place all your footer text in a child div that is positioned `relative` with respect to the top of the footer div.  The height of the footer div should be no smaller than the height of the background image.

Something like:

```
<div id="footer">
  <!-- hills bg image is attached here by CSS -->
  <div id="footer_content">
     blah blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#footer {
  min-height:387px; 
  background: url(image_URL) no-repeat;
}

div#footer_content {
  position:relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

Oh, and for heaven's sake.  Do not `position: absolute` your footer.  That's just nuts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the input, I'm still getting used to the "proper" ways of doing things, so thanks for showing me my errors. I did have the image on the footer before but keeping the footer at the bottom was an issue, and it still is now. This method works on a small resolution, but when a page has little content, the page doesn't fill the view port (or at least the hills don't sit at the bottom of the page). I'll have a fiddle once again. For now, thank you for the input!

Comment: Are you planning on having a lot of pages with very little content?  Seems to me you shouldn't be designing for fringe cases but for meat and potatoes.  Also, if I really helped you, please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 700px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

works.